# Count number of products foreach company

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.mvc to build some ERP and I am a little bit new to MVC. I am trying to find how can I make `Count` method foreach row in table (need to count from DB how much products each company have).

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountBusinessOffers(item.bId))
</td>
```

And the count method

```
public int CountBusinessOffers(int id)
    {
        DbHelper.ConnectRemoteDB();
        DbHelper.products_collection
                = DbHelper.Database.GetCollection<OfferItem>("products");
        var filter_byId = Builders<OfferItem>.Filter.Eq("bId", id);
        var filter_byDate = Builders<OfferItem>.Filter.Eq("isActive", true);
        var filter_byActive = Builders<OfferItem>.Filter.Gte("limitDate", DateTime.Now);
        var filter = filter_byId & filter_byActive & filter_byDate;
        var document = DbHelper.products_collection.Find(filter).Count();
        int numberOfItems = Convert.ToInt32(document);
        return numberOfItems;
    }
```

But I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.'

Comment: On which line you are getting this error?

Comment: You cannot use methods in `HtmlHelper` methods. Either use just `@CountBusinessOffers(item.bId)` or create a property in you view model and set to to the value of your `CountBusinessOffers()` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke Wow you are so right! Working great. just to use <td>@item.CountBusinessOffers(item.bId)</td>

Comment: Why dont you get the count right from the database using ```sql```?